# All set in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{usual})$, there are only $F_{\sigma}$ and $G_{\delta}$

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-topology, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Our teacher affirms this, but we have found a counterexample in the internet : $\mathbb{I}^{-} \cup \mathbb{Q}^{+} $ where:

$\mathbb{I}^{-}=\mathbb{I} \cap (-\infty,0) $ and $\mathbb{Q}^{+}=\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,\infty)$.

We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is  $F_{\sigma}$ (countable union of points, and  points are closed) and the complementary,  $\mathbb{I}$ is  $G_{\delta}$ because it is the complementary of an $F_{\sigma}$ .

We need to prove that  $\mathbb{I}^{-} \cup \mathbb{Q}^{+} $ isn`t an  $F_{\sigma}$.

Do someone could help us?

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $\mathbb Q$ isn't a $G_\delta$? Do you know the Baire category theorem?

Comment: What exactly is the claim? That each subset of  $\mathbb{R}$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ or a $G_{\delta}$?

Comment: I believe the claim is that every Borel set in $\mathbb R$ is either $G_\delta$ or $F_\sigma$.  This claim is, indeed, false.  The counterexample here is good.  The hint by @bof suggests how to prove that $\mathbb Q$ is not a $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb R$, which is easy to adapt to the cases in this proof.

Comment: We haven't given that theorem yet. Could you explain it in detail please?(
referring to the example)